# Why aren't hyperlinks opened in a new window?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

Just wondering, why hyperlinks don't open up in a new window. I know I can always open the link by right-click -> Open in a new window. Just a suggestion !

Comment: More answers, including keyboard shortcuts and a user script, at [make links posted by users open in a new window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*Hell, no!*

As Jakob Nielsen [puts it](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html):

> Opening up new browser windows is like a vacuum cleaner sales person who starts a visit by emptying an ash tray on the customer's carpet. Don't pollute my screen with any more windows, thanks (particularly since current operating systems have miserable window management). If I want a new window, I will open it myself!

You can easily *choose* to open a link in a new window by using a middle-mouse click, shift click, or whatever your OS and browser supports. But don't *force* it on me.

Comment: Wait... I'm *not* supposed to empty an ash tray on the customer's carpet? No wonder sales were down...

Comment: Though I couldn't agree more: amazing how a 15 years old post is still linked to from all over the internet. (I mean: opinions *could* have changed. But they have not, in this case. And neither as for the stupid "Reset form" button.)

Comment: @animuson I had a high school friend who sold vacuum cleaners door-to-door for a while and dumping an ash tray on the customer's carpet was actually part of the company-sanctioned pitch.

Comment: Then obviously some have different preferences. So why can't that be in a setting so people who feel the opposite could override the default behavior?

Comment: @toddmo: because every time a new preference is added you increase the complexity of the site; the developers have done a great job of keeping SO simple. At the same time it is *trivial* to use the `SHIFT` key when clicking on a link to open that link in a new tab. That little trick lets you, the user, control if that link is opened in a new tab *on a link by link basis*. When there is a much more powerful and flexible alternative available, the cost of making this a site preference is just not worth it.

Comment: I feel like this is a terrible generalization and there is a time and place for `_blank`.  Maybe not on SO, but definitely somewhere.  Also, what about automatically including the little "open-in-new-window" icon like wikipedia or similar?

Comment: what year is this? oh no my resources!!! please this is terrible. Sites now will typically warn you if you are leaving their when clicking on a link in "their" content. And as mentioned in my post these things are often referential in nature meaning having them both open is useful. the times i've clicked a link and closed the tab because i was expecting a new one is annoying.

Answer (score 7):

Opening links within the same tab conforms with [W3C principles](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G200.html). Automatically opening links in new tabs is difficult for sight impaired users and for security purposes. You can open links in new tabs using your keyboard short cuts.

Comment: Unfortunatly [WAI](https://www.w3.org/WAI/) is still not ranked high enough in the list of consideration when designing new apps or web-services - it's nice to see that some people trying to push its importance ;)