# Community Bulletin links should not force a new window

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, community-bulletin

The links in the Community Bulletin should behave in the same way as other links on SE.
I expect to control where the links are opened by choosing between left-click and middle-click. That isn't possible with the current settings.

Please remove `target="_blank"` from these links.

Comment: Also asked in MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230761/do-not-open-a-new-tab-for-links-at-the-community-bulletin

Comment: This is not just a feature request; it is a bug.  Reference: [Top 10 Mistakes in Web Design (number 9)](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-mistakes-web-design/)

Comment: @AnnaLear, this is clearly a bug.  These kind of links are an automatic fail to a usability audit.  Furthermore, [SE acknowledges the ***correct*** behavior as "Status by design"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252367/).

Comment: @BrockAdams What usability audit? You're asking for a change to current behavior of a particular feature that was deployed this way for a reason. It's not a bug. (For what it's worth, I agree that we should bring the bulletin in line with the rest of the links on the site.)

Comment: @AnnaLear, any audit performed by the company I linked or within companies where I've worked, like Cisco.  At least one government agency as well.  Not sure if/what federal law applies.  True this is not as much a "bug" as  grievous design flaw, but the tag is correct.

Comment: @BrockAdams it isn't a bug. Just because it is a usability issue and doesn't conform to particular guidelines, it does not make it a bug. It would only be a bug if SE decided those were the guidelines they'd follow, and implement it in such a way. Clearly they didn't, so it isn't a bug, but by design (and should be changed).

Comment: @BrockAdams It's incorrect in the context of how we use these tags. Check the tag descriptions.

Comment: @Joe, [they did acknowledge those guidelines, at least in part](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252367/).

Comment: @BrockAdams Nobody from SE has even acknowledged those guidelines in your link, just because that has been marked as status-by-design, it doesn't make this any more of a bug. It is a feature request, and hopefully one which will be acknowledged (though, I imagine it's pretty low-priority). If you still think this is a bug, we'll agree to disagree and leave it at that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next build, community bulletin links should behave the same way as other links on our sites. Keep an eye out for rev 2014.6.26.2343.

Comment: Thanks!  You can probably mark [the feature request on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230761/148310) as complete, too.

Comment: @BrockAdams Done! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

**I agree.** Users generally have got enough knowledge in manage cards opened by clicking left and middle button. That coudn't cause any data losing, because when we are leaving page while editing we're prompted. Using `target="_blank"` isn't recommended, just now. Please read following articles: [one](http://blog.silktide.com/2010/09/why-links-shouldnt-open-in-a-new-window/), [two](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/why-opening-external-links-in-new-tabs-should-no-longer-be-standard-behaviour/), [three](http://www.sitepoint.com/beware-opening-links-new-window/), there are many arguments agrees with OP's feature-request and I fully agree with them.