# Why do career links open in new tab?

Tags: discussion, meta

This is a pretty minor thing, but I find it odd that the "Looking for a job" links open in a new tab. All the other built-in links (minus adds) open in the same page. I don't find the career listings to be ads/ad-like, but maybe that's where opinions differ.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252367/why-arent-hyperlinks-opened-in-a-new-window) came up in the "similar questions" and the top answer had this quote:

> Opening up new browser windows is like a vacuum cleaner sales person who starts a visit by emptying an ash tray on the customer's carpet. Don't pollute my screen with any more windows, thanks (particularly since current operating systems have miserable window management). If I want a new window, I will open it myself! - [Jakob Nielsen](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/the-top-ten-web-design-mistakes-of-1999/)